# Visual Studio 2012 and Silverlight 5

Tags: visual-studio-2012, silverlight-5.0

Does VS 2012 come with SL 5?, if it doesn't, what can I do?, I guess the tools installed for VS 2010 don't work with VS 2012.

If I don't uninstall VS 2010, will Silverlight 5 work in VS 2012 without doing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MS SilverLight Forums](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/256578.aspx/1).

> does anyone know if          Silverlight 5 Tools for Visual Studio is
>   compatible with visual studio 2012 rc? i haven't found a vs2012
>   specific version.

With this answer

> Hi,
>
> You don't need that. You can create Silverlight projects directly in
>   Visual Studio 2012 RC. For more Visual Studio 2012 RC compatibility
>   issues please refer to:
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747(v=vs.110).aspx
>
> Sincerely,  Allen Chen  Microsoft Online Community Support
>
> Please remember to mark the replies as answers if they help and unmark
>   them if they provide no help.

So I assume that it's also true for the RTM release.

Comment: From this comment from Microsoft, I sence that we should call it "Silverlight" only.

Comment: I get "The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v5.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.CSharp.targets" was not found." when trying to open a Silverlight 5 project with a freshly isntalled VS2012 Web Express. I guess, I need something more. Silverlight Dev Runtime? Where is it?